# Some Unicode alt-codes not working

Tags: windows, keyboard, unicode

Here is a list of all special Hungarian characters:

```
ALT-0193 Á   ALT-0225 á
ALT-0201 É   ALT-0233 é
ALT-0205 Í   ALT-0237 í
ALT-0211 Ó   ALT-0214 Ö   ALT-0336 Ő
ALT-0243 ó   ALT-0246 ö   ALT-0337 ő
ALT-0218 Ú   ALT-0220 Ü   ALT+0368 Ű
ALT-0250 ú   ALT-0252 ü   ALT+0369 ű
```

All are working with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD</kbd> except the third column. I get ordinary `P`, `Q`, `p` and `q` letters instead of the letters given. What is the reason for this? What code should I input if I want to reach them?

- Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit
- Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_acute_accent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RonK answered the first part of your question.  The answer to the second part of your question is, as [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658.aspx) and [George Hernandez](http://georgehernandez.com/h/xComputers/CharacterSets/Shortcuts.asp#NumericKeypad) explain, to type <kbd>+</kbd> (on the numeric keypad) and then the *hexadecimal* value of the Unicode (UCS-16) character, all whilst holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down.  As George Hernandez writes, this mechanism is not enabled by default, and must be manually enabled after installing Windows.

Comment: The hexa code for 336 is 150. [ALT][+][0][1][5][0] and [ALT][+][1][5][0] both don't work.

Comment: George Hernandez explained it well: HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/EnableHexNumpad := REG_SZ("1")

Answer (score 7):

I don't have it of a certified source - but I think that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> only works for values in the range of `0..255`. So everything you try with a higher value is 'cast' down to this range.
So for example: 336-256=80.
Due to that -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>336</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>80</kbd>. Which is `'P'`.

**Edit:** The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> method only works on your active code-page, so it is actually typing characters in your local encoding (e.g. [ISO 8859-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) for Hungarian).
So basically keying <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>193</kbd> will type a character which is only 1 byte long and has the value `0xC3` (193 in HEX). By coincidence, `193` in ISO 8859-16 has the same display value as `\u0193` is the Unicode map. On my local codepage <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>193</kbd> produces the `┴` character which is `\u2534` in the unicode map.

My recommendation, if you need to display these values in some application, use the unicode convention instead of keying them in as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> combinations. You can download [BableMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) for this - it is a great tool for this purpose and is free.

Comment: Oh my god. Then what is the point in that it is an UNICODE code-position? Oh my god again.

Comment: @Notinlist - Added an edit to explain Unicode in this aspect